# Products are not updated via async API in Magento 2.4.6, though tasks are marked as succesful

Tags: magento2.4.6

When trying to update products via Magento async API, tasks are marked as succesfully accomplished, but products are not changed.

Almost all values under custom_attributes, including "tax_class_id" are not updated, except the "cost". Standard attributes "price" and "qty" are always updated.

Payload example:

```
[
  {
    "product": {
      "sku": 1000,
      "custom_attributes": [
        {
          "attribute_code": "attribute1",
          "value": 10
        },
        {
          "attribute_code": "attribute2",
          "value": 20
        },
        {
          "attribute_code": "attribute3",
          "value": 30
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first I found, that changes are reflected on website, just not visible from admin panel. This was solved by changing attributes scope to "Global" (default is "Store view"). Then reindex, flush cache and  here it is - all changes are visible in admin panel now.