# What method of product import and update you are using, if there are thousands of products with many custom attributes?

Tags: magento2.4, magento2.4.6

I've been using async bulk API to manage products, but [most of custom attributes are not updated this way in Magento 2.4.6](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/370266/products-are-not-updated-via-async-api-in-magento-2-4-6-though-tasks-are-marked) .

What are other popular methods which would do the job as well?

Update. As I found solution to [update custom attributes](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/370573/113881), product import and updates via API works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

We use a thrid party module [Wyomind Product import and update](https://www.wyomind.com/magento2/mass-product-update-import-magento.html). It works

Comment: While 3rd party software is a legit way to accomplish product import, It adds redundant complexity and dependence. Unless absolutely necessary, I tend to avoid stockpiling plugins on top of Magento, as I did with WooCommerce and prefer using core Magento functionalities.